# Why the WebView in my Android Project shows the link on the white screen instead of opening it?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-webview

I make a server project, which reads the domen from Firebase and loads the link. The WebView in my project must open this link, but instead of opening link it just shows it on on white screen. How to solve this problem? What did I do wrong?

Here's the WebActivity's code:

```
class WebActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityWebBinding
    val uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityWebBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val webIntent: Intent = intent
        val domen = webIntent.getStringExtra("Домен")

        val webSettings: WebSettings = binding.webView.settings
        webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        binding.webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(binding.webView,true)
        binding.webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        binding.webView.loadUrl("$domen/?packageid=$packageName&usserid=$uuid&getz=Europe/Moscow&getr=utm_source=google-play&utm_medium=organic")

    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if(binding.webView.canGoBack())
            super.onBackPressed()
    }
    
}
```

And here's a WebActivity's layout code (XML):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".WebActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is the screen of the app (WebActivity), which is shows the link:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zlhl.jpg)

I tried to swap `binding.webView.loadUrl("$domen/?packageid=$packageName&usserid=$uuid&getz=Europe/Moscow&getr=utm_source=google-play&utm_medium=organic")` and `binding.webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()`, but also I added `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` in layout WebView.

Comment: Did you try to replace that domain with common like google?

Comment: Why to replace the domain? I must read it from Firebase and paste to the link

Comment: I want to confirm that the web view display website normally. If that's true, you can change url in firebase to continue checking

Comment: Ok, I did it, and webView displays websites normally.  But I gotta add some additional information. The server must return either error 403, which contains "error" text, in this case I must open MainActivity (which has only text "Hello world"), or status 200 with this link, which I must remember in preferences and load it. Also the server needs to be accessed only once. P.S. this firebase file (google-services.json) is not mine, and I may not change link there